# Python cosmetic escapes for long string

Tags: python, flake8

I have something dumb that is annoying me. Using flake8 linter, they like the lines short obviously, if I run a string like below to continue on the next line:

```
print('\nWe interrupt this program to annoy you and make things \
          generally more irritating.\n')
```

This is what prints:

```
We interrupt this program to annoy you and make things               generally more irritating.
```

What is the proper way to continue a line of code without the large space between a printout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
print("\nWe interrupt this program to annoy you and make things "
      "generally more irritating.\n")
```

You don't need any continuation. Just put two string together with nothing in between, the Python parser will know it mean to concat them

This is called [string literal concatenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literal-concatenation)

Comment: Fine  for strings, I should have been more specific I guess, what about for lines where printing a string and a variable in the middle? like `'string' + var + 'string'`?

Comment: Yes, beautiful! Thank you! Will accept in 5 minutes when timer runs down

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest putting the long string into a variable and printing the variable.

```
message = ("We interrupt this program to annoy you and make things "
           "generally more irritating.\n")
print(message)
```

Python handles the string continuation automatically because it is wrapped in the parentheses.